# Read Windows event logs using Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise library 3.1 to log application logs in Windows event logs, and I want to read this log by passing the date parameter.

Please note that I will be accessing the remote machine and the performance should be good. Is there any method that can be used to read these logs using Ent Lib, or please suggest some good method.

Answer (score 0):

For event log manipulation, you should directly use .NET classes,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815314

Regards,